# Pig latin method

Tags: java, methods

This is part of my Pig Latin. It is a method, I need to return the first vowel of the word. If there are no vowels I want to return the word length. But I have an error when I return the length of the word. The error is in "else" when returning isVowel.

```
private static int indexOfVowel(String word) {
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
            if (isVowel(word.toLowerCase().charAt(i))) {
                return index;
            } else {
                return isVowel(word.length());
            }
            
    } 
    
    private static boolean isVowel(char ch) {
        switch (ch) {
        case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'u':
        case 'y':
        return true;
        default: return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass an integer to a method that expects a character. I think what you wanted is if you didn't find a vowel anywhere in the word, you want to return the length of the word.

Therefore you need to return word.length() after the for loop is done i.e. you looked at all characters in the word and didn't find a vowel. The method needs to be written as :

```
private static int indexOfVowel(String word) {
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        if (isVowel(word.toLowerCase().charAt(i)))
            return index;
    return word.length();
        
}
```

Comment: I think it's also worth noting that the OP was trying to return a boolean from a method with a return type of integer.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong Yes I believe OP would find it soon with this answer.